# sending variables to a JQuery function

Tags: jquery

I'm a novice in jQuery, but I hope somebody will be able to help me out.  I have searched this forum (and others) but haven't been able to find an answer that I could make work.

I have a link like this:

```
<a href="#">
```

and a jQuery script:

```
$("div.show_dialogbox").click(function(){
    $("div#dialogboxwraper").animate({
        height: "400px"
    }, "slow")
    .animate({
        height: "200px"
    }, "slow");
});
```

I would like to be able to send a variable with the link and use it in the script for the height like this:

```
<a href="#" OnClick="variable(200)">


$("div.show_dialogbox").click(function(variable){
    $("div#dialogboxwraper").animate({
        height: variable+200+"px"
    }, "slow")
    .animate({
        height: variable+"px"
    }, "slow");
});
```

Comment: Soory ... im dyslexic and english is not my nativ language

Answer (score 7):

I would use data attributes here, for which more support was added in jQuery 1.4.3, like this:

```
<a href="#" class="show_dialogbox" data-height="200">
```

Then in jQuery:

```
$("a.show_dialogbox").click(function(){
  $("#dialogboxwraper").animate({
    height: $(this).data('height') + 200
  }, "slow")
  .animate({
    height: $(this).data('height')
  }, "slow");
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/QgdRt/).

Comment: @Jesper - It's valid in HTML5, and at the same time, causes no issues with HTML4.

Comment: Well ... the site is in XHTML (strict) :( ... and must validate

Comment: I like the ideer .. hover i see another problem with it ... how cud it be used if i want multiple variables ?

Comment: @Jesper - You can use `data-somethingelse` or put JSON into one attribute, either way.

Comment: Nick, how do you get so many up votes? I gave you one too, but still.. :)

Comment: @Sandro - in this case probably because many aren't aware of the `.data()` enhancements in 1.4.3, they gets data out as a number (parsed), object, etc...so very handy.

Comment: I knew of the data function, but I didn't realize the data was parsed. Just one more reason to like jQuery :)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about explicity sending a variable but you could set the `title` of the anchor to be "200px" and then inside of your function do something like

```
var h = $(this).attr('title');
```

Comment: Thanks .. might be usefull ... but i woud prefere to use the title as a title for the link

Answer (score 1):

well make a function than;

```
<a href="#" OnClick="shoot(200)">
```

///

```
function shoot (number) {

    $("div#dialogboxwraper").animate({
        height: number+200+"px"
    }, "slow")
    .animate({
        height: number+"px"
    }, "slow");


}
```

NOTE: You will have to add `onclick="shoot(200);"` on every  that processes that

Comment: I didn't see this and wrote essentially the same code and had to delete. I think this is the best idea. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a plugin that animates to a certain class, this way you separate the display portion of your site from the data portion of your site. You'd create a CSS class for the "opened" state and another for the "closed" state, then use one of the plugins below to animate between them.

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/animate-to-class

jQuery UI, also extends the animate class so you can do this:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/switchClass/

Here's a demo, this uses jQuery UI:

http://jsbin.com/ijewu3

And the edit link:

http://jsbin.com/ijewu3/edit

Comment: Im not shure i understand what you meen ... I want to use the script for multiple content ... the box will load its content when opend ... so i have multiple heights for for the same box

Comment: You would create a class for each type of content, then depending on the type of content the user loads, you switch the class to properly display that content. I'll try to give you an example in a little bit.

Comment: Tahnk you ... ill look forward to se that

Comment: I updated my post a little while ago. See the new demo links. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this would be to move the code that actually initiates the animation to a seperate function like so:

```
function doSomeAwesomeAnimation(variable){
   $("div#dialogboxwraper").animate({
        height: variable+200+"px"
    }, "slow")
    .animate({
        height: variable+"px"
    }, "slow");
}
```

Then you would wireup your click event on your link like so:

```
$("div.show_dialogbox").bind("click", doSomeAwesomeAnimation(200));
```

Edit:  one quick point your selector you are using to wireup the click event is targeting a div with a class of show_dialogbox not the link html element it presumably contains.  Just wanted to make sure you knew that.

Comment: Yes thanks .. i have moved that selector :-) ... and thanks for the input

Answer (score 0):

html tags can have rev="" and rel="" strings which can be parsable. You may also look into something like this: `...

This will set a tag parameter and then continue with whatever else is supposed to happen after clicking.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help and inputs/ideers :-)

I ended up using vertazzar answer, because i found it to be the one suting me needs best (and beeing the easy

This is what i ended up with

The links:

```
<a href="#" OnClick="showdialogbox(350,'test1');" class="show_dialogbox">Dialog test 1</a><br /><a href="#" OnClick="showdialogbox(200,'test2');" class="show_dialogbox">Dialog test 2</a>
```

and the function

```
    // SHOW DIALOG BOX
function showdialogbox (boxh, boxc) {
    if ($("div#dialogboxwrap").css("height") === "0px") {
            $("#dialogboxcontent").load("test1.html #"+boxc);
    }
    else {
        $("div#dialogboxwrap").animate({
            height: "0px"
            }, "slow",function(){
            $("#dialogboxcontent").load("test1.html #"+boxc);
        });
    }
    $('div#dialogboxcontent').css('height', boxh-80+"px");
    $("div#dialogboxwrap").animate({
        height: boxh+100+"px"
    }, "slow")
    .animate({
        height: boxh+"px"
    }, "slow");
}
// CLOSE DIALOG BOX
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("div#close_dialogbox").click(function(){
        $("div#dialogboxwrap").animate({
            height: "0px"
        }, "slow");
    });
```

the result can bee seen here (comments are velkome) http://www.gynther-klanen.dk/hr/

Now how do i close this question and can i somhow credit you here ???